# create eclipse run configuration with maven archetype

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

i have the following problem - i would like to create a project with a maven archetype that also automatically creates necessary run configurations that will be available through the eclipse interface.

Tbh i couldnt find anything on the internet related to this and i'm not sure if it's even possible to kinda hook into the eclipse system to create these starters with maven but it'd still be super cool and would make things a lot easier for project setups.

So looking at an archetype it doesnt seem like i can actually trigger some logic with it, right? It just creates the environment for the project without offering any other purpose?

Would it be possible to maybe call a maven goal right after the archetype was created that somehow can then create the run configurations for the project?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there is a `.launch` file somewhere within a project, Eclipse displays the launch configuration in the UI. So all you have to do is to create this XML file. In the launch configuration go to the _Common_ tab and choose _Save As: Shared file_ to see what such a file should look like.

Comment: thanks @howlger! It's working now after adding the *.launch files to the archetype. Didn't know that it would be that easy and convenient to add these to the eclipse UI tbh x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a `*.launch` file somewhere within a project, Eclipse displays the launch configuration in the UI. So all you have to do is to create this XML file:

1. In the **launch configuration** go to the *Common* tab and choose ***Save As: Shared file*** to save the launch configuration within your project
2. **Add** the the **`*.launch`** files **to the Maven archetype**